# How to fix this Sql code to give the names of student and their grades who got better grades than the highest grade by gray in classes taught by KEEN

Tags: oracle

I have 4 tables which are class, student, faculty, and grade.
I want SQL to give the names of students and their grades who got better grades than the highest grade by GRAY in classes taught by KEEN.

Here is a sample of what I did

```
 SELECT S_NAME, GRADE
        FROM GRADE1
        WHERE GRADE >(SELECT GRADE FROM GRADE1 G
        INNER JOIN CLASS1 C ON G.C_NAME=C.C_NAME
        INNER JOIN aggarwal.FACULTY1 F ON F.F_NAME
        WHERE G.S_NAME='GRAY' AND F.F_NAME='KEEN');
```

> ERROR at line 6:
>   ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Any help as to how?

Comment: Change `SELECT GRADE FROM GRADE1` in the sub select to `SELECT max(GRADE) FROM GRADE1 ` and see if you get the results you wanted.

Comment: And change your tag from sql-server to oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The last `INNER JOIN` is a culprit; its `ON` clause doesn't contain everything it should - what are you joining `F.F_NAME` to?

Besides, a few more objections:

- always use table aliases, especially when working with subqueries because you might find yourself puzzled getting result you didn't expect
- subquery misses the `MAX` function; generally speaking, you should take care that it returns a single value, otherwise you'll get `TOO-MANY-ROWS`, unless you apply `ALL` (or `ANY`), e.g.

  ```
  where r.grade > any (select g.grade from grade1 g ...)
  ```
- why did you precede table name with its ownere, here: `aggarwal.FACULTY1`? Don't all of your tables belong to the same schema? If so, remove it (or, for consistency, use it with all other tables as well).

Finally, your query might look like this:

```
select r.s_name, r.grade
from grade1 r                                            --> missing alias(es)
where r.grade > (select max(g.grade)                     --> missing MAX
                 from grade1 g
                 inner join class1 c on g.c_name = c.c_name
                 inner join faculty1 f on f.f_name = ... --> missing value here
                 where g.s_name = 'GRAY' 
                   and f.f_name = 'KEEN'
                );
```